# warning: Can not parse XML library list; XML support was disabled at compile time error

Tags: xml, parsing, gdb

I am using GDB debugger on Windows 64bit system and I want to see what are the values stored in the registers, but after I have attached to the process I keep getting "warning: Can not parse XML library list; XML support was disabled at compile time" error. I have already tried installing the Expat XML parser and tried running the command but for some random reason it doesn't recognize it even I have set the PATH for it.

Could someone advice me what I should do with XML parser and where I should extract the files of it?

- Den

Answer (score 4):

GDB you are running was built without XML support, so there is nothing you can do to fix this executable.

You can either find another build of GDB or build it from source yourself (and make sure you have libexpat-dev installed on build machine).

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install libexpat-dev
```

The docs say https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Running-Configure.html#Running-Configure :

> --with-expat
>
> Build GDB with Expat, a library for XML parsing. (Done by default if libexpat is installed and found at configure time.) This library is used to read XML files supplied with GDB. If it is unavailable, some features, such as remote protocol memory maps, target descriptions, and shared library lists, that are based on XML files, will not be available in GDB. If your host does not have libexpat installed, you can get the latest version from ‘http://expat.sourceforge.net’.